# Which element is giving StaleElementReferenceError?

Tags: ruby, dom, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So my code is giving me `` [remote server] resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:8325:24:in `fxdriver.cache.getElementAt': Element is no longer attached to the DOM (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError) ``

There are several elements being used in the code, and I am trying to see which element is giving me this error so I can make sure there is a `wait` for it.

**EDIT**
Here is the code:

```
path = [".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a", ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a", ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a", ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/a", ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[3]/a", ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[3]/a", ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]/a", ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[3]/a", ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[3]/a", ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[3]/a"]
path.each do |path|
    begin
        wait.until {
            element = browser.find_element(:xpath => path)
            element if element.displayed?
        }
        browser.find_element(:xpath => path).click
        table = wait.until {
            element = browser.find_element(id: "possible_matched")
            element if element.displayed?
        }
        if table 
            puts "Table Found"
        else 
            puts "Table Error"
        end
        #creates an 2D array containing patient name, admit date and prints to screen
        names = browser.find_elements(:xpath => ".//*[@id='possible_matched']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")
        name_array = []
        names.each { |name| name_array << name.text}
        admits = browser.find_elements(:xpath => ".//*[@id='possible_matched']/table/tbody/tr/td[5]")
        admit_array = []
        admits.each { |date| admit_array << date.text }
        name_admit_array = name_array.zip(admit_array)
        name_admit_array.each do |name, date|
            puts "#{name}: #{date}"
        end
        #finds the location of the sub-array containing patient name and collection associated admit date
        patient_name = browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='dialog-modal-cancel-hl7-preview']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").text
        collected_date = browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='dialog-modal-cancel-hl7-preview']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]").text
        puts patient_name
        puts collected_date
        mo, da, yr = collected_date.split('/').map(&:to_i)
        cd = [yr, mo, da]
        bl = name_admit_array.each_with_index.select { |(name, date), i|
            m, d, y = date.split('/').map(&:to_i)
            dt = [y, m, d]
            name.downcase == patient_name.downcase and (dt <=> cd)<0
        }.map {|x, i| i }

        blf = name_admit_array.values_at(*bl)
        if bl.any?
            bf = blf.rindex(blf.max) + 2
            wait.until {
                element = browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='possible_matched']/table/tbody/tr[#{bf}]/td[6]/div/a")
                element if element.displayed?
            }
            browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='possible_matched']/table/tbody/tr[#{bf}]/td[6]/div/a").click
        else
            browser.find_element(:xpath => "html/body/div[6]/div[1]/a/span").click
        end
    end while bl.any?
end
```

Comment: Please add in the code.  Generally `StaleElementException` is caused when an element is located, the page changes, and an attempt is made to use the element after the page changes.  A page can change due to clicks in the page, or by visiting another page and returning.  Most likely this can be fixed by making sure a new reference to elements is obtained after an action is performed which makes changes in the page.

Comment: Added the code. I see what is happening (the element is being changed because the DOM is updated even though the xpath stays the same) I just have no idea how to fix it or see exactly when it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check the complete stack trace of the error, it would point to the exact line which threw the exception.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am totally new at all this. How do I check the stack trace?